# Python: Sort a list according to two attributes

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of the following kind:

```
class Ind(object):
    def __init__(self,ID,mate):
        self.ID=ID
        self.mate=mate

population=[Ind(8,None), Ind(1,2), Ind(20,3), Ind(2,1), Ind(12,None), Ind(3,20), Ind(10,11), Ind(11,10)]
```

You can think of this list `population` as a population of individuals which all have an `ID`. Some of them have a `mate` (an individual who is present in the same population or the same list). The `mate` value is actually the `ID` of the mate! Therefore, if there is an instance of `Ind` which attributes `ID` equals 12 and `mate` equals 34, then there is necessarily an individual in the list whose `ID` equals 34 and whose `mate` equals 12. Individuals that do not have a `mate` have `None` in the `mate`attribute. Does it make sense?

I'd like to sort this list so that the first individual mates with the last one, the second individual mates with the second-to-last individual, etc... The individual which attribute `mate`equals `None` should stand in the middle of the list.

There are many possible outputs that fit what I want. Here is one example of these outputs for the above list:

```
population=[Ind(1,2), Ind(20,3), Ind(10,11), Ind(8,None), Ind(12,None), Ind(11,10), Ind(3,20), Ind(2,1)]
```

Comment: is there a requirement to actually sort the result as well?

Comment: Looking at your example, it seems an Individual can have two different mates : there's `Ind(2,3)` (2 mates with 3) and `Ind(2, 1)` (2 mates with 1). Is this a typo ? Or is mating really a one-to-many relationship in your population?

Comment: Indeed there was a mistake in my example. Sorry about that. I corrected it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
def custom_sort(population):
    pop_dict = { ind.ID: ind for ind in population }

    start = []
    nones = []
    end = []
    for ind in population:
        if ind.mate is None:
            nones.append(ind)
        elif pop_dict[ind.mate] not in start:
            start.insert(0, ind)
            end.append(pop_dict[ind.mate])
    return start + nones + end
```

This is under assumption that "being a mate" is a 1-to-1 relation.

Answer (score 2):

You just need a key for the sorting function. The following example requires that individuals are monogamous and not married to themselves. It also requires that if (a,b) is listed, (b,a) is also listed. If these prerequisites are not met and Ind(2,1) can occur without Ind(1,2), this function will place Ind(2,1) towards the end of the list. The first index in the key function is the type: "first" in relationship (where IDmate) comes third.  These first and second types are sorted in order by their ids; last type is sorted in reverse order by its mate.

```
def keyfun(x):
   if x.mate==None: 
     return (1,x.ID)
   elif x.ID<x.mate: 
     return (0,x.ID)
   else:
     return (2,-x.mate)

sorted(population,key=keyfun)
```

Another way to handle this, still assuming that if (a,b) is in the list (b,a) will also be in the list, is to just preprocess by removing (b,a) cases, then postprocess by adding them back in in reverse order.

Comment: You're right...I don't know why I was thinking otherwise. Edited :)

Answer (score 0):

How about this.  Split list into three lists, one with `ID < mate`, the second with `ID > mate`, and the third with `mate is None`.  Then, concatenate the sorted lists, each sorted via ID.

I've added a `__repr__` method to the `Ind` class for output readability.

```
class Ind(object):
    def __init__(self,ID,mate):
        self.ID=ID
        self.mate=mate

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Ind({},{})'.format(self.ID,self.mate)

population=[Ind(8,None), Ind(1,2), Ind(2,3), Ind(2,1), Ind(12,None), Ind(3,2), Ind(10,11), Ind(11,10)]

def custom_sort(pop):
    singles, less, more = [], [], []
    for p in pop:
        if p.mate is None:
            singles.append(p)
        elif p.ID < p.mate:
            less.append(p)
        elif p.ID > p.mate:
            more.append(p)
    comp = lambda x,y: cmp(x.ID,y.ID)
    return sorted(less,cmp=comp) + sorted(singles,cmp=comp) + sorted(more,cmp=comp,reverse=True)


print custom_sort(population)
```

This outputs:

```
[Ind(1,2), Ind(2,3), Ind(10,11), Ind(8,None), Ind(12,None), Ind(11,10), Ind(3,2), Ind(2,1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot you can do with costum key functions:

```
def my_key(ind):
    if ind.mate is None:
        return 0
    if ind.ID < ind.mate:
        return -ind.ID - 1
    else:
        return ind.mate + 1
population.sort(key=my_key)
```

This assumes that IDs will never be negative. If IDs are always greater than 0, you can discard the `- 1` and `+ 1`.